# Adapting text into a tikz shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to adapt the text to the border of the inner shape of this image?
[image]

I would like to have something like this (the text should be somehow "stretched"):

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[cyan, rounded corners] (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6,0) -- cycle;
\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\clip[rounded corners] (10,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2) -- ([turn]0:1) -| (11,0) -- cycle;
\draw[green!80!black, line width=50pt, rounded corners] (15,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\clip[rounded corners] (10,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2) -- ([turn]0:1) -| (11,0) -- cycle (-1,-3) rectangle (11,7);
\draw[red, line width=50pt, rounded corners] (15,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2);
\end{scope}
\draw[white, line width=15pt, rounded corners] (15,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2);
\node[scale=3] at (2.89,2.7) {\sffamily
 \scalebox{1.9}[4.5]{AIS}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to do it *by hand* with `\draw` commands.